# Angular .config not being called

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I've been beating my head against what is probably a stupid mistake for the last couple hours.  My angular .config module isn't being called and I can't figure out why.

In an effort to eliminate potential sources of trouble, I've reduced my app down to only the entry point index.js file and and am not injecting any dependencies other than ngRoute.

All the files are being loaded just fine and I can trace code execution to the app.config line but breakpoints inside the passed function never get hit and neither of the console.logs ever fire.  What am I doing wrong here?  I've made angular apps before and never had this issue.  I've probably got a typo somewhere that I'm missing but damned if I can find it.

My *index.html:*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/css/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row" id="controls">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="row" id="content">
        <div ng-view></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row" id="footer">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular-route.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/services.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/controllers.js"></script>-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

My *index.js*:

```
'use strict';
/*global angular*/

var app = angular.module('pagednaApp', ['ngRoute'/*, 'pagednaApp.services', 'pagednaApp.controllers'*/]);

app.config(function($scope, $routeProvider){
  console.log('test');
  console.log($scope);
  $routeProvider
  .when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'content.html',
    controller: 'mainController'
  });
});
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you've forgotten the

```
ng-app="pagednaApp"
```

Comment: Ah, thanks.  I knew it was something simple I had missed.  Will mark as solved as soon as SO lets me.

Answer (score 6):

put ng-app

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="pagednaApp">
```

Comment: Thanks!  Unfortunately, Yang Li beat you by a few seconds. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could do `angular.bootstrap` on your page. That will initialize angular on page.

Add below code to your HTML page.

**CODE**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    angular.element(document).ready(function() {
        angular.bootstrap(document, ['pagednaApp']);
    });
</script>
```

Thanks.